# Flex 3: Error #1069 on Embedded Google Map

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps

I've got a Flex 3 app (a Google map) embedded in a WordPress page. It's been working fine for a few weeks. I just went to check the page, and I got the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property at not found on com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONParseError and there is no default value. at 
com.google.maps.core::UsageTracker/onLoadComplete()
```

Any ideas as to what this means and how to fix it? I didn't know that I was using JSON.

Comment: Same here. @meagar did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

AS3 error 1069 appears when you have misspelled a property or function and have not assigned a value to it.

From http://curtismorley.com/2008/07/16/365/

Wrong:

```
var t = new Timer(1000, 60);
t.addEvent(TimerEvent.TIMER, Tick);
```

Correct:

```
var t = new Timer(1000, 60);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Tick);
```

Comment: Hi Todd, Thank you for the message. When I googled this error, I saw Curtis' explanation. I wonder if something with Google Maps has changed as the code worked fine previously. I'm not sure what UsageTracker is. Thank you.

Comment: Google changes its API. I had it happen to me before. Perhaps that is what is going on. Take out parts of the code until you find the offending piece then find a substitute with the Google API.